# Save ScriptableObject modification

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a ScriptableObject that is modified by player, so I would like to save changes.
For this, I use EditorUtiliy.SetDirty() or EditorSceneManager.markSceneDirty().
However, these methods belongs to UnityEditor, that is impossible to include in a build. My question is, how can I build my scene ?

Brett

Comment: You simply must not use `EditorUtiliy.SetDirty()` or `EditorSceneManager.markSceneDirty()`. Instead, the data of your scriptable object should be serialized and deserialized into a file.

Comment: Look at [XML serializer](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php%3Ftitle%3DSaving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer&ved=2ahUKEwinnY2KjdzZAhWMO5oKHYXQCo4QFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1F7Fy_Q_2R9KJl3qtQXcXN) (if a script contains stuff from UnityEditor you have to surround it with the preprocessor `if UNITY_EDITOR ........ #endif` (c#)  but this of course will not be executed than in the build)